# Plotting Modis time series in R

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot Modis NDVI time series in R but my code doesn´t work.

I created a dataframe with my time information:

```
files <- list.files()

find_date <- function(file_name) {
  year <- substr(file_name, 35, 38)
  num_days <- as.numeric(substr(file_name, 39, 41))
  as.Date(num_days, origin = paste0(year, "-01-01"))
}

# Create an empty dataframe
dates <- data.frame(file_name = character(), date = Date(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Iterate over each file name and find the date
for (file in files) {
  date <- find_date(file)
  
  # Append the file name and date to the dataframe
  dates <- rbind(dates, data.frame(file_name = file, date = date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}

# Print the resulting dataframe
print(dates)


colnames(dates)[2] = 'Datum'
head(dates)
tail(dates)
```

and then tried to plot it:

```
year.x =2000
```

```
spplot(ndvi_corrected[[year.x]], col.regions = viridis(100),        names.attr = dates$Datum[year.x],         main = paste('NDVI', dates$Datum[year.x[1]], 'bis', dates$Datum[year_dates[length(year.x)]])) 

spplot(ndvi_corrected[[36]], col.regions = viridis(100),
       names.attr = dates$Datum[year.x], 
       main = paste('NDVI', dates$Datum[36]))
```

the lower plot works fine, while the upper plot gives me this error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :    Error evaluating argument 'obj' in method selection for function 'spplot': not a valid subset
```

I am new to R, sorry for the basic question!